# How to import COM into Ironpython?

Tags: .net, com, ironpython

In Cpython, I can use win32com.

But, in ironpython, I didn't know how to import it.

Because, in .net, one always use Visual Studio to interop the COM and to use it.

Comment: IronPython documentation has three approaches for creating a COM object: https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#creating-a-com-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to create an IDispatch object using:

```
from System import Type, Activator
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(com_type_name))
```

This is equivalent to win32com.client.Dispatch(com_type_name).

If there's a type lib you should be able to do:

```
import clr
import System
typelib = clr.LoadTypeLibrary(System.Guid("00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"))
word = typelib.Word.Application()
```

I don't know what that's equivalent to.  I'm not much of an expert on this but I took those from [IronPython's cominterop_util](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/75792#1090265) which is used in the tests.  There's more stuff in the IronPython\Tests\interop\com directory which might be useful.